# Problem with old video data

Tags: 18.04, video, dvd, cd

so I've videos from 2000 year on my CD/DVD disks, problem is that I can't play that videos, I mean it plays but just 5-7 second, next happen data allocated, I see that video is going -1, -2, -3 ... seconds and after that system freezes. Next when I try to run video again, it shows me just black blank(I hope that this videos aren't destroyed). Btw surface of disks looks like clear, without any damage.

So have anyone idea what to do? how to run that videos and how to fix black blank's problem.

Comment: Hi cike4ka! I understand you're trying to play videos from a DVD. Is it a data DVD that contains different video files or is it a video DVD. What kind of software are you using to play the videos?

Comment: Yes it contains also other files, without videos. when I first time play video, system request some drivers(I don't remember) I clicked download. I tried to check history what I downloaded, but there is nothing

Comment: Alright, perfect! You might just be missing a codec. Try installing the VLC media player and opening the video files with it. In order to do so search for it in the Ubuntu Software Center or type `sudo apt install vlc` in a terminal. Then right click the file you want to play, select `Open with different app` and then select `VLC Media Player`.

Comment: Thank you @Béné. It works! :3

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is truly a burned CD/DVD disk from the year 2000 you most likely are experiencing data degradation from the media. I have disks that were kept in clear cases on the shelf for a couple years. Just the small amount of sunlight that got onto the disks was enough to alter the ink (the ink reacts to UV light after all, that's how the initial data was written to disk) and render the disks unreadable. And that was after just 7 years.

If you value the data on the disks, you will most likely want to to back these up right away.

My personal recommendation is to use **ddrescue** ([Stackexchange Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77834/how-to-rip-a-scratched-dvd-video-a-cdparanoia-for-dvds)) to try to make a disk image you could potentially re-burn onto another DVD (use a slow write speed if this is for long storage! But I don't recommend using DVDs for storing valuable data!).

Comment: Thank you for good advice, and what you think about videos which I play and now show me black blank, is there any possibility to be lost that videos?

Comment: @cike4ka Not sure. I have experienced similar issues when trying to play back videos from bad media. Copying to a known good media (HDD for example), and trying to play it back from there might give you a clue whether it is permanently damaged. Then you can see if it is a codec issue, as Bene suggested.